# Use my HDMI port as an input

Tags: windows, video, hdmi

I've an HDMI port on my Windows laptop. I often use it as an output port connected to a TV.
I need to do the opposite.
I would like to know if it´s possible to connect an other hardware (this one send the video through its own HDMI port) on my laptop port in order to **use my laptop screen as à display?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware connections.

Comment: @Remo.D on which StackExchange forum can I ask?

Comment: @fractaliste usually i would post you the link to the hardware stack exchange. BUT for that what you want to do you better ask some Electrical Engineering guys here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

and i wish you best of luck ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure which one is most suited but SE is for programming questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is NO. The LCD on a notebook/laptop can't be accessed with the system's on-board HDMI port. The HDMI port on the notebook/laptop is an output port, not an input port.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got more information about it and most of video cards have only HDMI input. Only some very specifics one's provides it.